# Select method of Worksheet Class Failed Error when opening another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

```
Sub Copy()

Workbooks("Data.xlsm").Sheets("28May2020").Select

Workbooks("Data.xlsm").Sheets("28May2020").Activate

Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COPYHERE").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("COPYHERE").Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = Date
Sheets("COPYHERE").Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Value = Time

Range("L43:X93").Copy Worksheets("COPYHERE").Range("A" & lastrow + 2)

Sheets("COPYHERE").Select

Timer

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Timer()

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "Copy"

End Sub
```

Comment: Whenever i am opening another workbook my VBA coded sheet shows error.

Comment: It would be better to just [avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: And [Use `Long`, not `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: Where are you opening another workbook?

Comment: @braX i am opening the another workbook in my same desktop

Comment: @BigBen i am a beginner in VBA unable to replace anything... can you please guide ...

Answer (score 0):

Before `Sheets("COPYHERE").Select`, place a line `ThisWorkbook.Activate`. That activates the workbook running the code.

Also take another look at
`Sheets("COPYHERE").Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = Date`
`Sheets("COPYHERE").Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Value = Time`
`Range("L43:X93").Copy Worksheets("COPYHERE").Range("A" & lastrow + 2)`
Sheets, Worksheets and Range refer to ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet. Unless you're sure that's what you want, I recommend you change Sheets to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets`, Worksheet to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet` and Range to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(<sheet name>).Range(<address>)`.

Comment: Thanks brother for your advice now its working fine either open many no of worksheet together

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Copy()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim wsName As String
Dim cpName As String

wsName = "28May2020"
cpName = "COPYHERE"
Sheets(wsName).Activate

lastrow = Sheets(cpName).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets(cpName)
    .Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = Date
    .Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Value = Time
End With

Range("L43:X93").Copy Worksheets(cpName).Range("A" & lastrow + 2)

Sheets(cpName).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for ur advice but now sheet is working fine